# Slim Routing - Routes ignored

Tags: php, routes, slim

I've a problem how to model my routes so they get recognized correctly. I've the following routes:

```
$app->get('/courses/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $app->render(200, array("Id parameter"));
});

$app->get('/courses/attendees', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render(200, array("attendee Parameter"));
});

$app->get('/courses/search', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render(200, array("search Parameter"));
});
```

If I call the URI localhost/courses/12 I'll get the expected result "Id parameter" but if I call the URI localhost/courses/search or localhost/courses/attendees I still get the same result.

Seems I'm missing something here...

Comment: Reorder the routes. The `search` route must be before the `:id` route. Slim uses the first route that matches.

Comment: So Slim can't distinguish if it is an parameter or a 'static' part of the URI, right?

Comment: That is right. Use conditions to limit `id` to numbers, and it will work. http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Conditions

Comment: Thank's Fracsi! I'will check Route-Conditions for further informations.

Comment: I agree with @Fracsi. Just to add to what was said, based on your particular example, you might benefit from structuring your routes within route groups: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Groups (Then it might be more obvious to see that the first route is actually matching all the requests)

Comment: It is not that "Slim can't distinguish" something. It uses first route that matches. Just reorder your routes properly.