# Silm routing php

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I have created a database in mySql and have a page for portfolio items. However when I try to create a link to an item of the portfolio via the id I keep getting errors.

I have had a look at the slim [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)

I have also had a look at various questions already here on stackoverflow, including;

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735735/slim-routing-routes-ignored)

There were a few more I viewed about group routing, but am still getting confused. I have read on the internet about using PDO for it, but have not covered that yet. I am wandering if there is a way to route a portfolio item when clicked on to a template, where the url will use the id number of the row in the mysql table?

Here is my index file, if you need to see more please let me know.
Many thanks

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set ( "Europe/London" );


$app = new \Slim\Slim( array(
  'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));


$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = array(
    'debug' => true,

);

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
);

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass','tom_db')
or die('Error Connecting to mysql server');

$query = "SELECT id  FROM documentaries";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row["id"];
}



//what happens here is what will run with our object
$app->get('/', function() use($app){
  $app->render('about.twig');
});


//portfolio page
    $app->get('/portfolio', function() use ($app) {
        $app->render('portfolio.twig');
    });

    $app->get('portfolio/{id}', function ($id) {
        $app->render('portfolioitem.twig', array(
            'data' => $data
        ));
    });

$app->get('/contact', function() use($app){
  $app->render('contact.twig');
})->name('contact');

$app->run();


?>
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

The error I am having is that when clicking on a portfolio link it does not render the url portfolio/1 however if I manually enter the url in to the browser it renders the html with no styles. I am rendering a twig file, but it does not seem to be working

Here is my updated index file;

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
date_default_timezone_set ( "Europe/London" );

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app = new \Slim\Slim( array(
  'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig()
));


$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = array(
    'debug' => true,

);

$view->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
);

//what happens here is what will run with our object
$app->get('/', function() use($app){
  $app->render('about.twig');
});

//portfolio page
$app->get('/portfolio', function() use($app){
  $app->render('portfolio.twig');
})->name('portfolio');

//this is function where the problem is, when in the portfolio.twig file it does not link to this
$app->get('/portfolio/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    // include out mysql connection code and make the connection
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'tom_db');


    // query the database
    $rs = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM documentaries WHERE id=$id" );

    // convert the record set into an associative array so we can work with it easily
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);


    $app->render('portfolioitem.twig', array(
            'data' => $data
        )
    );
});


$app->get('/contact', function() use($app){
  $app->render('contact.twig');
})->name('contact');

$app->run();


?>
```

Edit: additional twig files added

This is my portfolioitem.twig

```
{% extends 'main.twig' %}

{% block nav %}
     <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ baseUrl() }}" >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/portfolio') }}" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/clients') }}">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/teaching') }}">Teaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
 {% endblock nav %}
{% block content %}

  <section>
    <h2>This is a test</h2>
  </section>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is my portfolio.twig

```
{% extends 'main.twig' %}

{% block nav %}
     <ul>
        <li><a href="{{ baseUrl() }}" >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/portfolio') }}" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/clients') }}">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/teaching') }}">Teaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
 {% endblock nav %}

{% block content %}

      <section>
        <div class="showreel-container">
         <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/148640837?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>

        <div id="controls" id="Controls">

            <button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter=".documentaries">Documentary</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter=".charity">Charity/NGO/Commisions</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter=".music">Music</button>
            <button class="filter" data-filter=".drama">Drama</button>

        </div>



        <div id="Container" class="container">

          <div class="mix documentaries" data-myorder="1"><a href="portfolio/{{ data.id }}"><img src="img/numbers-01" alt="Image one"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix commercial" data-myorder="2"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-02" alt="Image two"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix commerical" data-myorder="3"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-06" alt="Image six"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix charity" data-myorder="4"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-09" alt="Image nine"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix music" data-myorder="5"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-12" alt="Image twelve"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix drama" data-myorder="6"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-01" alt="Image one"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix music" data-myorder="5"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-12" alt="Image twelve"/></a></div>
          <div class="mix charity" data-myorder="5"><a href=""><img src="img/numbers-12" alt="Image twelve"/></a></div>

          <div class="gap"></div>
          <div class="gap"></div>

        </div>


      </section>

{% endblock content %}
```

Finally this is my main.twig file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% block head %}
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Tom Turner - Director of Photography</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsivemenu.js"></script>

    {% endblock head %}
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <h1>Tom Turner</h1>
        <h2>Director of Photography</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        {% block nav %}
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ baseUrl() }}" class="selected">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/portfolio') }}">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/clients') }}">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/teaching') }}">Teaching</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ siteUrl('/contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        {% endblock nav %}
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="wrapper">

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}

    </div>

     <footer class="main-footer">
       {% block footer %}


        <div id="footer-notes">
          <p>Tom Turner - Director of Photography</p>
          <p>&copy; Tom Turner - All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
       <div id="mayur">
          <p>&copy; 2015 Website by <a href="https//:www.mayurpande.com">Mayur Pande</a></p>

        </div>

        <div class="social-media">
          <ul>

              <li><a href="mailto:tom@allritesreversed.co.uk"><img src="img/mail_circle.png" alt="Email Logo" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tom.turner.397501?fref=ts"><img src="img/fbcircle.png" alt="Facebook Logo" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://vimeo.com/user6107855"><img src="img/vimeo_circle.png" alt="Vimeo Logo" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=mayurpandeuk"><img src="img/twitter_circle.png" alt="Twitter Logo" /></a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
       {% endblock footer %}
      </footer>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsivemenu.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

my htaccess file;

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please, can you add the errors that you get?

Comment: @DavidePastore thank you for viewing I have edited my question.

Comment: Also include your template files.

Comment: @DavidePastore sorry should have included them straight away. They are included now. Many Thanks

Comment: As it stands this question doesn't make sense.  After re-reading It sounds like your routing is working; as in `/portfolio/1' is resolving correctly.  But you are having trouble generating/rendering links.  However there is no example of a portfolio item link being generated.

Comment: @Progrock '/portfolio/1' is working if I manually enter the url to the browser, however it does not apply the style sheet to it. With regards to the generating/rendering link. In my portfolio.twig file it can be seen that the first item in my portfolio div container. It has a link that portfolio/{{ data.id }}. But this doesn't seem to render "portfolio/1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheets are relative to the current URL path, so when you are at

`/portfolio`, it will look for `/portfolio/main.css`. Update your link elements to include the site URL, or make them relative to the root, by using `/main.css` (note the `/` at the beginning).

The same applies to the links in your templates, `portfolio/{{ data.id }}` will try to point to `/portfolio/portfolio/{{ data.id }}`, again, add the site url to the beginning, or add the slash.

If you are using Slim V3, consider using https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View
Alternatively for V2, use https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views, ***edit:*** just noticed that you are already using this.

It allows you to name your routes, e.g:

```
$app->get('/portfolio/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
    ...

    $app->render('portfolioitem.twig', array(
            'data' => $data
        )
    );
})->name('portfolio.id');
```

And then reference the urls in your template with

```
{{ urlFor('portfolio.id', {"id": 17 }) }}
```

This means that if ever your URLs change, all links referencing it are automatically updated at the same time.

You will also need to make sure that your `.htaccess` file is configured correctly. As shown in the Slim documentation at http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/, it should contain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

### Issue 2

You are running your query which results an array of results in `$data`, however you are trying to access the first result using `{{ data.id }}`, first, you need to loop over the data using

`{% for item in data %}`, then you will be able to use `{{ item.id }}`. Alternatively, get the first item from your PHP like `$data = $data[0]`, and then pass that into your template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am still getting errors. With regards to including the site url, as I am using xampp it does not allow me access. With regards to naming routes it came up with the error;  An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Named route not found for name: portfolio.id") in "portfolio.twig" at line 38

Comment: If you are using `xampp`, make sure that your `httpd.conf` file is correct `AllowOverride All   <--- make sure this is not set to "None"`

Comment: This still is not working. I have changed the .htaccess from what I have shown above to what you have done and have set the `httpd.conf` to `"None"`. Here is what my link to porfolio/id looks like at the moment;             `"http://localhost:8080/portfolio/{{ data.id }}"` is this correct? Sorry about this your probably getting bored of this now.

Comment: No, it says make sure that it is **not** set to None

Comment: Are you seeing that URL when you click the link? Or is that how it appears in your template? The rendered page should replace `{{ data.id }}` with the actual ID.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: This is how it appears in my template. When I click the link it it takes be back to /porfolio/ with no styles.

Comment: See my updated question above, if you do `print_r($data)` in your PHP, you will see that it is an array of data, you need to get the first item in that array before you can access it's properties.

Comment: Would I loop through `data`` within the template file?

Comment: It all depends what you want to do. If you want a list of portfolios, list in the template. If you want to display the first/only row that is returned from the DB, pull it out from the PHP

Comment: still seem to be getting errors, if I clink the link it takes me to the /portfolio page without styles. And now if I manually enter it gives me an error exception with the message: undefined offset. Thank you for the help, I will try to sort this out.

Comment: Just check your network inspector, see where it is trying to look for the CSS etc, fix the links, use things like `print_r` on variables to make sure they look like they should etc. Good luck